# How to perform http2 requests to ksqldb in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http2, ksqldb, nodejs-stream

I'm trying to figure out how to make http2 requests to [ksqldb](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/streaming-endpoint/). I found this [project](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksqldb-graphql/blob/master/packages/ksqldb-client/src/queryStream.ts) which successfully does it (I adapted to it to js code below). However, this code is using async generators while I want to create a simple client which makes a one-off request and that's it. This is my adaption:

```js
const http2 = require('http2');

const DELIMITED_CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/vnd.ksqlapi.delimited.v1';

const parseChunk = (buf) => {
  return buf
    .toString()
    .split('\n')
    .filter((str) => str);
};

const main = () => {
  const session = http2.connect('http://localhost:8088');
  const stream = session.request({
    [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_PATH]: '/query-stream',
    [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_METHOD]: 'POST',
    [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE]: DELIMITED_CONTENT_TYPE,
  });

  const query = {
    sql: `SELECT * FROM test_view where name='john';`,
  };
  const reqPayload = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(query));
  stream.end(reqPayload);

  stream
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
    .on('close', () => console.log('close'))
    .on('abort', () => console.log('abort'))
    .on('timeout', () => console.log('timeout'));

  let chunk;
  let nextLines = '';
  console.log('before while');
  while ((chunk = stream.read())) {
    nextLines += parseChunk(chunk);
    console.log('nextLines', !!nextLines);
  }
};

main();
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work: `chunk` is always null. I don't understand what I am missing from the original [project](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksqldb-graphql/blob/master/packages/ksqldb-client/src/queryStream.ts). I adapted the Typescript file to a Javascript file in order to easily run it (it works):

```js
const http2 = require('http2');

const DELIMITED_CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/vnd.ksqlapi.delimited.v1';

class QueryStream {
  closed = false;

  constructor(session, queryStreamArgs, mapRow) {
    this.session = session;
    this.queryStreamArgs = queryStreamArgs;
    this.mapRow = mapRow;
  }

  headers() {
    return {
      [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_PATH]: '/query-stream',
      [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_METHOD]: 'POST',
      [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE]: DELIMITED_CONTENT_TYPE,
    };
  }

  parseChunk(buf) {
    return buf
      .toString()
      .split('\n')
      .filter((str) => str);
  }

  initQueryStream() {
    const stream = this.session.request(this.headers());

    // we write params into the request stream, then end the request stream.
    // if we don't end the request stream, the req isn't routed on the server.
    // note that the _response_ stream does not close, so we still get results.
    const reqPayload = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(this.queryStreamArgs));
    stream.end(reqPayload);

    return stream;
  }
}

class AsyncIteratorQueryStream extends QueryStream {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    // array of resolve/reject tuples represents pending work
    // const promised: [(ret: any) => void, (err: any) => void][] = [];
    const promised = [];

    // unprocessed query response lines returned by the server
    const received = [];

    const stream = this.initQueryStream();

    const destroyStream = (err) => {
      // close existing promises
      for (const [resolve, reject] of promised) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          const [error] = received;
          try {
            const parsedError = error && JSON.parse(error);
            if (parsedError?.status === 'error') {
              reject(new Error(parsedError.message));
            } else {
              return resolve({ value: received, done: true });
            }
          } catch (e) {
            reject(new Error(e.message));
          }
        }
      }

      stream.destroy();
      this.closed = true;
    };

    stream
      .on('error', (error) => destroyStream(error))
      .on('close', () => destroyStream())
      .on('abort', () => destroyStream(new Error('abort')))
      .on('timeout', () => destroyStream(new Error('timeout')));

    // the work loop delivers query result data by delimited row.
    // given demand, reads next buffer from the stream if available.
    const doWork = () => {
      if (this.closed) {
        return;
      }

      // process available query response lines
      while (promised.length && received.length) {
        const [resolve] = promised.shift();
        const rawJson = received.shift();
        resolve(rawJson);
      }

      if (promised.length) {
        // pending work is unfulfilled; try to read it from stream
        const next = stream.read();
        if (next != null) {
          const nextLines = this.parseChunk(next);
          received.push(...nextLines);
        }
        // loop work
        setImmediate(() => doWork());
      }
    };

    // enqueue work to be handled by the work loop
    const nextPromise = () =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => promised.push([resolve, reject]));

    // the first promise parses query response metadata and returns col names.
    const getRowKeys = nextPromise().then((rawMeta) => {
      try {
        let meta = {};
        if (typeof rawMeta !== 'string' && rawMeta.value) {
          meta = JSON.parse(rawMeta.value[0]);
        } else if (typeof rawMeta === 'string') {
          meta = JSON.parse(rawMeta);
        }
        if (meta.status === 'error') {
          const err = meta;
          destroyStream(err);
          throw err;
        }
        return meta.columnNames;
      } catch (e) {
        destroyStream(new Error(e.message));
      }
    });

    doWork();

    // return async iterator contract
    return {
      next: () => {
        if (this.closed) {
          return Promise.resolve({ value: undefined, done: true });
        }

        // enqueue the next row handler
        return getRowKeys.then((ks) => {
          const enqueued = nextPromise().then((rawRow) => {
            const value = this.mapRow(rawRow, ks);
            return { value, done: false };
          });

          doWork();
          return enqueued;
        });
      },

      return: () => {
        destroyStream();
        return Promise.resolve({ value: undefined, done: true });
      },
    };
  }
}

const asyncIteratorQueryStream = (session, queryStreamArgs, nameKey) => {
  const mapRow = (rawRow, ks) => {
    let row = [];
    try {
      row = JSON.parse(rawRow);
    } catch (e) {
      row = [rawRow];
    }
    return ks.reduce(
      (acc, k, i) => {
        acc[nameKey][k] = row[i];
        return acc;
      },
      { [nameKey]: {} }
    );
  };
  return new AsyncIteratorQueryStream(session, queryStreamArgs, mapRow);
};

const main = async () => {
  const session = http2.connect('http://localhost:8088');
  const q = asyncIteratorQueryStream(session, {
    sql: `SELECT * FROM test_view where name='john';`,
  });

  for await (const row of q) {
    console.log('row', JSON.stringify(row));
  }
};

main().catch((e) => console.error(e));

// usage
//
// const session = http2.connect('https://localhost:8089');
// const q = asyncIteratorQueryStream(session, { sql: 'select * from foo' });
// (async () => {
//     for await (const row: Record<string, any> of q) {
//         // ...
//     }
// })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote a code version which works (nodejs version 14):

```js
class KsqlDBClient {
  constructor(ksqlDBBaseUrl) {
    this.client = http2.connect(ksqlDBBaseUrl);
    this.client.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
  }

  request(query) {
    const session = this.client.request({
      [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_PATH]: '/query-stream',
      [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_METHOD]: 'POST',
      [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE]:
        'application/vnd.ksql.v1+json',
    });

    session.setEncoding('utf8');
    session.on('data', (queryResult) => {
      console.log('queryResult', queryResult);
    });

    const payload = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(query));
    session.end(payload);
  }
}

  const query = {
    sql: `SELECT * FROM test_view emit changes;`,
  };
  const client = new KsqlDBClient('http://localhost:8088');
  client.request(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some error while parsing the chunks, but this worked for me, used a JSONstream parser library:

```
class KsqlDBClient {
 constructor(ksqlDBBaseUrl) {
  this.client = http2.connect(ksqlDBBaseUrl);
  this.client.on("error", (error) => console.error(error));
}

async request(query) {
  const key = process.env.KSQLDB_KEY;
  const secret = process.env.KSQLDB_SECRET;

  const session = this.client.request({
    [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_SCHEME]: "https",
    [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_PATH]: "/query-stream",
    [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_METHOD]: "POST",
    [http2.constants.HTTP2_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE]:
      "application/vnd.ksql.v1+json",
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(key + ":" + secret, 
                    "utf8").toString("base64")}`,
  });

  session.setEncoding("utf8");

  let data = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const parser = JSONStream.parse();
    session.pipe(parser);
    parser.on("data", (queryResult) => {
      console.log("data", queryResult);
      data.push(queryResult);
    });
    parser.on("error", (error) => {
      console.error(error);
      reject(error);
    });
    session.setEncoding("utf8");
    session.on("end", () => {

    // handle your data here

      this.client.close();
      resolve(data);
    });

      const payload = JSON.stringify(query);
      session.end(payload);
    });
  }
}
```